# Bluemix API connect POST request (form data) file attachment issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

In API connect, I was working with one of the 'path' in API which requires file upload using multipart/form-data (POST request). I was not able to find out any support for it though.
While adding parameter there is no support for 'file' type (located-in: form-data). Is there something which I am missing in my setup? Is there any other way to attach file in request via API connect ?
I am using API Connect "Essentials" plan.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can just leave the `type` blank:
[image]